# Am I mixing up different design patterns?

Tags: oop, models

In my application I currently have a URL model class and a URLQuery class.

My URL class has a few properties and a save method that uses the injected database class to save the object and it's properties to the database.

My URLQuery class has a method for taking in some conditions and returning rows from the database and instantiating them as URL objects from the URL class.

Recently however, I have come to feel that maybe my code is mixing different design patterns. For example, the URL model class needs the database class injected into it and it feels messy to instantiate a URL class and setup it's dependencies inside another class that may be just to do with crawling the URL etc.

So this is when I look into using a factory class with a database dependency and injecting it into my other classes. It could have methods like:

- create - This would take in parameters and instantiate a URL class there and then return it.
- save - This would take a URL object and save it to the database

Would this make sense?
Does my URLQuery also make sense or am I miss-using another design pattern?
I'm just confused, as I see in so many tutorials etc the usage of a save method directly in a model class etc.

Comment: @niksofteng Yes, I'm just still deciding which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your dilemma. When we start learning design patterns, we start thinking they should/must always be used and forget about the problem we are trying to solve. Identifying design-pattern before identifying the problem, is a problem itself.

Your scenario is actually simple, and so keep the code simple too. [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

You need just one model/entity URL, one class to save/read from db and then a crawler that just needs URLs, nothing else.

```
public class URL {
    // only properties
}

// You inject this repository whenever you want to work with db
public class URLRepository {
    // This will talk to db
    public URL Get(<param>) { } // fetch from db
    public int Save(<param>) { } // save to db, and return it's ID
    // .. and so on
}

public class Crawler {
    // This is just concerned about URL objects
    // nothing else
}
```

Comment: I wondered about using the URLQuery to be like a factory as well so it saves and gets in once class. This is helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with what we have. First URL is a model class and seems like URLQuery is a handler/controller class. You have a database which needs CRUD operations, which could go into the controller class itself, lets say DB.

Now lets try to separate out functionality. By that, I mean that Model should not care where it's data is coming from. Similarly, Model nor controller need to know how db is setup and/or whether the db is a relational or not. Think of controller only as a logical flow handler. DBWrapper need not know what object of which class it is saving, controller should only tell it to save X data in Y format to save in Z table.

So, how I would do it is this

```
class URL
{
  // Variables/methods go here

  String Serialize()
  {
     // This is the data that gets saved to DB. You could return Object, to hide the type
  }

  static URL Deserialize(String serializedURLModel)
  {
    Object xyz = /* extract data from serializedURLModel here*/;
    return new URL(xyz);
  }
}
```

Then the Controller class takes control, and drives the logic around...

```
public class URLQuery
{
    DB db;
    public void createURL(URL url)
    {
        if(!db.HasTable(URLTable))
            db.createTable(URLTable); //Assume that you are creating columns and their types here.

        db.put(URLTable, url.GetID(), url.Serialize());
    }

    public void getURL(String urlID)
    {
        return URL.Deserialize(db.getObjectforColumn(URLTable, urlID));
    }
}
```

Finally, I would have a class DBWrapper and have it return DB, which is an interface. So outside the DBWrapper class, the controller doesn't know which db it is and how it is implemented. Something like the following:

```
interface DB
{
    void createTable(String Tablename, ... etc);
    void GetObjectForColums(String tableName, String column);
}

public class DBWrapper
{
    public static getDB()
    {
        return new MySQL_DB();
    }

    private class MySQL_DB implements DB
    {
        void createTable(String Tablename, ... etc) // implement it here
        void GetObjectForColums(String tableName, String column) //implementation
    }
}
```

Hope Its helpful :)